# laravel 5.3 Api routes not returning "unauthorized access" error.

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create an api with laravel 5.3 and I've just created a new fresh **Laravel 5.3** project and have added the below route to the **routes/api.php** file.

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    return view('welcome');
});
```

When I hit this url **http://localhost/api/** on my browser I was navigated to the default laravel home page of my application.

Now my question is, shouldn't I get an "Unauthorized access" error when I try to access a route in the **api.php** file without passing a token? Why is laravel letting me navigate to the api route even when I'm not passing a token?

**Note: I have not added laravel passport or any other oAuth libraries to the project yet.**

Comment: Does the answer work for you?

Comment: Yes it did, Like you said we would have to use a middleware such as auth or a custom one of our own. Thanks for your help.

Comment: More than welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Laravel doesn't check those by default when defining routes like that. And thats a good thing because there might be situations where you provide information without the user needing to send a crsf token or authenticate.

What you want is using middleware in your routes. Have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

This will use the specified middleware like 'auth' on certain routes or route groups. i.e.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::post('profile', 'ProfileController@create');
    ....
}
```

Also see the example on the page with the middlewareGroups 'web'

Comment: The middleware `auth` will use the default guard, you want `auth:api` assuming that the name wasn't changed.

Comment: auth:api works, I'd go a step further and use the `api` group, then throttles are handled as well. All that is explained in the given link. The code is an example of how it can be used. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I was trying to implement the "client_credentials_grant" using passport, which doesn't required a user therefore can not use the auth middleware. Instead I found this https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/6b4adcca0b604e163454e1ca63871a516b0b5b48/src/Http/Middleware/CheckClientCredentials.php .For anyone whos looking to implement "client credentials grant" with passport, this is the solution you are looking for.